# How do you control pinch and zoom speed for a UISCrollview?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, zooming, pinch

Pinch and zoom is way too violent of an animation need to turn it down a notch.

Answer (score 0):

well i came up with this:

since speed seems to be dependent on the min and max scroll speeds i kept them close to the min and max zooms every time it actually zooms using the uiscroll delegate

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

 if(scrollView.multipleTouchEnabled){

 CGFloat fSpeedZoom=.02;

 scrollView.maximumZoomScale=scrollView.zoomScale+fSpeedZoom;
 scrollView.minimumZoomScale=scrollView.zoomScale-fSpeedZoom;

 if(scrollView.maximumZoomScale>fMaxZoomScale) SV.maximumZoomScale=fMaxZoomScale;
 if(scrollView.minimumZoomScale<fMinZoomScale) SV.minimumZoomScale=fMinZoomScale;

 }
}
```

would be good to hear f there are other ways, or if this is flawed.

Comment: this is dependent on processor speed - seeing variations of speed on each platform, adding a timing component to this may help