# Increasing UIScrollView pinch zoom speed/rate?

Tags: ios, performance, uiscrollview, zooming, pinch

I would like to decrease the finger movements required to zoom in a UIScrollView, any ideas how to do it?

I came across the following [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4157442/3046504), but can't get it to work.

Comment: Try `UIPinchGesture` it has velocity see here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPinchGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPinchGestureRecognizer/velocity

Comment: Looks good, but this would mean I need to build the UIScrollView bicycle again.. Still, say there's a way to redefine the UIScrollView [pinch gesture recognizer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6724771/3046504), how would I then implement the zooming back?

Comment: You don't need UIScrollView for this, it will work on simple UIView.

Comment: But I do need a UIScrollView.. as it's a central piece of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no officially supported way to do this. Apple tries to keep these things the same across apps and this is probably why the limitation.